# Output all results of findstr to seperate txt files

Tags: windows, batch-file

Currently my code is: `findstr Starfy ./List.txt > result.txt`

My result.txt is

> 3841 - Legendary Starfy, The (USA).zip

> x166 - Legendary Starfy, The (USA) (Demo) (Kiosk).zip

However, I want result 1 and result 2 to have their own seperate files, so it would look like:

result1.txt > 3841 - Legendary Starfy, The (USA).zip

result2.txt > x166 - Legendary Starfy, The (USA) (Demo) (Kiosk).zip

I'm unsure how to make this work, and would love if someone is able to help point me in the right direction.

Comment: We expect a [mcve]. That means you submit the content of `List.txt`, a genuine `STRING1`, and the content of the resultant output file, _(`result.txt`)_. Then based only on those things, explain exactly what you want your new output files to contain, and the exact names you wish them to have. There is an **edit** button beneath your question, _or you can click on this [edit] link_, and make the required changes. Please ensure that you use the appropriate formatting options when you post your updated information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr "Starfy" .\List.txt ^| findstr /N "^"') do >result%%a.txt echo %%b
```

Just pass your original results into another instance of `findstr /N` command that add line numbers. After that, separate the number and the line in a `for /F` command and output each line to its corresponding numbered file...

Comment: This is what worked the best for my use case. Thank you!

Comment: Just be aware that any line begining with one or more `:` characters, would have those leading characters omitted from the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%S in ('findstr /i "echo" "%~f0"^|findstr /n /i "echo" ') do ECHO %%T>"U:\moreresults\result%%S.txt"
```

The command quoted in parentheses finds a string (in this case, `echo`) ignoring case (`/i`) within the file `"%~f0"` (this batch file, which contains a heap of standard code I use for testing). This is passed to another instance of `findstr`, this time looking for the same string, but numbering the lines (as serialnumber:linetext).

The resultant text is tokenised using `:` as a separator, so `%%S` receives the  serialnumber and `%%T` receives the rest of the line (token `*`). Then simply build the result filename using `%%S` and write the text part of the line to it.

The caret is used to `escape` the pipe so that `cmd` knows that the pipe is part of the command-to-be-executed, not of the `for` command.

Comment: Just be aware that any line begining with one or more `:` characters, would have those leading characters omitted from the output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you do not already have files in the location you're outputting your results, which could alalready be named using that intended naming scheme, then something like this may suit you:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "Starfy" 0^<".\List.txt" 2^>NUL'
) Do (
    Set /A i += 1
    1>"Result!i!.txt" Echo %%G 
)
```

Please note that I used `find.exe` instead of `findstr.exe` simply because your example used a simple string containing a series of alphabetic only characters. Feel free to change it to `'%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:"Starfy" ".\List.txt" 2^>NUL'`, or similar, should you require a more specialized matching mechanism.